# F# use named tuple as function parameter

Tags: f#, tuples, c#-to-f#

I have the following type in F#:

```
type CodeNameError(CodeNameCombination: (Code*Name)[]) =
member this.CodeNameCombinations = CodeNameCombination
```

Is there a way to turn the (Code*Name)[] into a named tuple array in F#?
In c# I would do something like:

```
public CodeNameError((Code code, Name name)[] codeName)
{
    CodeNameCombination = codeName
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# does not have named tuples in the same way in which C# has them, but there are a couple of alternatives. My preferred option would actually be to just define a new record type for the `Code * Name` pair. If you get into a situation where you want to name things, a record is a good choice and it takes 1 line of code:

```
type NamedCode = { Name:Name; Code:Code }

type CodeNameError(codeNameCombination:NamedCode[]) =
  member this.CodeNameCombinations = codeNameCombination

CodeNameError [| { Code = "1+1"; Name = "test" } |]
```

If you do not want to define a type (but I'm not sure why you wouldn't want to do this), you could use anonymous records:

```
type CodeNameError(CodeNameCombination: {| code:Code; name:Name |}[]) =
  member this.CodeNameCombinations = CodeNameCombination

CodeNameError [| {| code = "1+1"; name = "test" |} |]
```

Comment: I had been passing a named tuple from c# into an F# type which took a tuple.  The output at the end looked a little wonky.  Thanks for the info.